# i get these error about "No routes matched location "/product/2"

Tags: reactjs, redux

in the HomeScreen all the products get displayed but when i click on a single product to view the product details and perhaps add it to cart , i dont see the productscreen at all and the console says " No routes matched location "/product/2"  here is my productscreen

```
import React, { useEffect} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';    
import { listProducts } from '../actions/productActions';


function HomeScreen(props) {
    const productList = useSelector(state => state.productList);
    const {products, loading, error}  = productList;
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    useEffect(() => {
       dispatch(listProducts());
        return () => {
            //
        };
    }, [])   

    return loading ? <div>Loading...</div>:
    error ? <div>{error}</div>:
    
     <ul className="product">
   
        {
            products && products.map((product) =>
            
                <li key={product._id}>
                    <div className="product">
                      <Link to={'/product/' + product._id}>
                         <img className="product-image" src={product.image} alt="product"></img>
                      </Link>
                      <div className="product-name">
                       <Link to={'/product/' + product._id}>{product.name}</Link>
                      </div>
                      <div className="product-brand">{product.brand}</div>
                      <div className="product-price">{product.price}</div>
                      <div className="product-rating">{product.rating} Stars ({product.numReviews})</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                )
        }
    </ul>
}
export default HomeScreen;
```

server.js

```
import express from 'express';
import data from './data';

const app = express();


app.get("/api/products/:id", (req, res) => {
    const productId = req.params.id;
    const product = data.products.find(x => x._id === productId);
    if(product) 
      res.send(product); 
    else 
      res.status(404).send ({ msg : "Product Not Found."}) 
     
});

app.get("/api/products", (req, res) => {
    res.send(data.products);
});

app.listen(5000, () => {console.log("Server started at http://localhost:5000") });


app.js

import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter,Route,Routes,Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import CartScreen from './screens/CartScreen';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import ProductScreen from './screens/ProductScreen';

function App() {

  const openMenu =() => {
    document.querySelector(".sidebar").classList.add ('open');
  }
  const closeMenu = () => {
    document.querySelector(".sidebar").classList.remove('open');
  }
  return (
<BrowserRouter>
    <div className="grid-container">
      <header className="header">
        <div className="brand">
          <button onClick={openMenu}>
            &#9776;
          </button>
          <Link to="/" >LETS SHOP 4U</Link>
        </div>
        <div className="header-links">
          <a href="cart.html">Cart</a>
          <a href="signin.html">Sign In</a>
        </div>
      </header>
      <aside className="sidebar">
        <h3>Shopping Categories</h3>
        <button className="sidebar-close-button" onClick={closeMenu}>x</button>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="index.html">Vegetables</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="index.html">Fruits</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="index.html">Grains</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="index.html">Meat</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="index.html">Oil</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="index.html">Tuber</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="index.html">Cereals</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="index.html">Spices</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="index.html">Others</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </aside>
      <main className="main">
        <div className="content">
          <Routes>
          <Route path="/products/:id" element={<ProductScreen/> } />
          <Route path="/cart/:id?" element={<CartScreen/>} />
          <Route path="/" exact={true}element={<HomeScreen/>} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </main>
      <footer className="footer">
        All right reserved.
      </footer>
       </div>
       </BrowserRouter>
      );
      }
  export default App;


ProductAction

mport axios from "axios";
import {PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST, PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS, PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL, 
  PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST, PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS, PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL} from "../constants/productConstants";

const listProducts = () => async (dispatch) => {
    try {

        dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST });
        const {data} = await axios.get("/api/products");
        dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS, payload: data});
    
    }
    catch (error) {
        dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL, payload: error.massage});
    }  
}

const detailsProduct = (productId) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST, payload: productId});
    const {data} = await axios.get("/api/products/" + productId);
    dispatch({type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS, payload: data});
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL, payload: error.massage});
    
  }

}
export { listProducts, detailsProduct };  


productscreen.js


import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { detailsProduct } from '../actions/productActions';
import { addToCart } from '../actions/cartActions';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function ProductScreen (props) {
    
  const {id} = useParams();
  const [qty, setQty] = useState(1);
  const productDetails = useSelector(state => state.productDetails);
  const { product, loading, error } = productDetails;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(detailsProduct(id));
  }, [dispatch]);

  const handleAddToCart = () => {
    props.history.push(`/cart/${id}?qty=${qty}`); // use template literals to include the id and qty in the URL
};
 

  if (!product) {
    return <></>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className='back-to-result'>
        <Link to='/'>Back to result</Link>
      </div> 
      {loading ? <div>loading...</div>:
       error ? <div>{error}</div>:
      (
        <>
          <div className='details'>
            <div className='details-image'>
              <img src={product.image} alt={product.name}></img>
            </div>
            <div className='details-info'>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <h4>{product.name}</h4>
                </li>
                <li>
                  {product.rating} Stars ({product.numReviews} Reviews)
                </li>
                <li>
                  Price: <b>{product.price}</b>
                </li>
                <li>
                  Description:
                  <div>{product.description}</div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div className='details-action'>
              <ul>
                <li>Price: {product.price}</li>
                <li>
                  Status:{' '}
                  {product.countInStock > 0 ? 'In Stock' : 'Unavailable'}
                </li>
                <li>
                  Qty:
                  <select
                    value={qty}
                    onChange={(e) => {
                      setQty(e.target.value);
                    }}
                  >
                    {[...Array(product.countInStock).keys()].map((x) => (
                      <option key={x + 1} value={x + 1}>
                        {x + 1}
                      </option>
                    ))}
                  </select>
                </li>
                <li>
                  {product.countInStock > 0 && (
                    <button
                      onClick={handleAddToCart}
                      className='button primary'
                    >
                      Add to Cart
                    </button>
                  )}
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className='details'></div>
        </>
      )};
    </div>
  );
}

export default ProductScreen;
```

i have tried all possible solutions i can think of.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your are using mismatched syntax

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/products/:id" element={<ProductScreen />} />
  // other routes
</Routes>

import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
```

then for your function ProductScreen(props)

```
add const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleAddToCart = () => {
    navigate(`/cart/${id}?qty=${qty}`); 
  };
```

should do it, or at least get you closer to a solution.